# Can logstash be used as a kafka forwarder?

Tags: logstash, scalability, kafka

I am looking at the plugins for Logstash and I noticed it had both an input and output plugin for kafka.  For a single topic, can Logstash be used to forward kafka topic messages to another kafka server or should I expect there to be some data loss?

Answer (score 0):

Logstash is a extract/transform/load framework designed to handle log-structured data. It should be able to be that forwarder, and has the ability to transform the data while it is forwarding it.